# Creating a List<Book> c# console application

Tags: c#

I want to create a List that holds a couple of books with the book title, authors name and year of publication. example: ( AuthorLastName, AuthorFirstName, “The book title”, year.)

I know how to create `List<int>`, for example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    list.Add(10);
    list.Add(20);
    list.Add(25);
    list.Add(99);
    }
}
```

But the problem is, if I want to create a list of books, I can't simply make a `list<string>` or `list<int>` because I want it to contain strings and int's (as the example above).

So, Can anyone explain how I can make a List of books?

Comment: Define your class `Book`

Answer (score 6):

You need to create a `class` called `Book` that contains the properties you want to have. Then you can instantiate a `List<Book>`.

Example:

```
public class Book
{
   public string AuthorFirstName { get; set; }
   public string AuthorLastName { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

And then, to use it:

```
var myBookList = new List<Book>();
myBookList.Add(new Book { 
                         AuthorFirstName = "Some", 
                         AuthorLastName = "Guy", 
                         Title = "Read My Book", 
                         Year = 2013 
                        });
```

Comment: @user2057693 Are you aware you can mark this question as the answer? If  you do you will be awarded more reputation yourself and it will help others identify quickly the information they need if they encounter a similar problem.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define your class:

```
    public class Book 
    {
       public string Author { get; set; }
       public string Title { get; set; }
       public int Year { get; set; }
    }
```

Then you can make a list of them:

```
var listOfBooks = new List<Book>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this

```
            public class Book
            {
                public string AuthorLastName { get; set; }
                public string AuthorFirstName{ get; set; }
                public string Title{ get; set; }
                public int Year { get; set; }
            }

            List<Book> lstBooks = new List<Book>();
            lstBooks.Add(new Book()
            {
                AuthorLastName = "What",
                AuthorFirstName = "Ever",
                Title = Whatever
                Year = 2012;
            });
```